# Creating a dictionary for renaming columns and column entries automatically in R

Tags: r, function, dictionary

I have data as follows:

```
df_a <- data.frame(x = c("season", "season", "season", "package", "package"), x1 = c("1","2", "3", "1","6"))

df_b <- data.frame(y = c("seaason", "lalala", "package", "paackage", "pakkage", "blabla"), y2 = c("1","2", "3", "2", "4", "6"))

df_c <- data.frame(z = c("season", "sessson", "saeson", "package", "pakkage"), y3 = c("1","2", "3", "2","6"))

df_a
        x x1
1  season  1
2  season  2
3  season  3
4 package  1
5 package  6

df_b
         y y2
1  seaason  1
2   lalala  2
3  package  3
4 paackage  2
5  pakkage  4
6   blabla  6

df_c
        z y3
1  season  1
2 sessson  2
3  saeson  3
4 package  2
5 pakkage  6
```

The data frames above have different column names (`x, y and z`), but they reflect the same information. Apart from the varying column names, also the way the types (`season and package`) are not (always the same).

In real life, this is the result of individuals who do not work together, using different naming conventions for the same thing. This creates a lot of issues, because not only do I manually have to connect these column names, I even have to try to fuzzyjoin the types..

I am thinking if it is possible to make some kind of dictionary which tells me that `x, y and z` are actually the same things (let's say `x == y|z`), and something similar for the types (`season == sexson | seaason | etc.`).

I thought the best way would maybe be to create a function that scans each df for column names in the dictionary, copies them and converts them to the name of my choice, doing the same for the column content.

I am trying to think of sum function which I can feed the dictionaries.

```
dfs <- c(df_a, df_b, df_c)
vector_of_column_names <- c("x", "y", "z"

column_conversion <- function(dfs, vector_of_column_names) {
  for (i in dfs) {
    index <- match(names(dfs[i]),vector_of_column_names)
    names(dfs[i])[index] <- vector_of_column_names[1] # The first vector item is the name used. 
  }
}
```

I'm having a bit of trouble of how to start this dictionary though. Are there any suggestions?

Desired output:

```
df_a <- data.frame(x = c("season", "season", "season", "package", "package"), x1 = c("1","2", "3", "1","6"))

df_b <- data.frame(y = c("seaason", "lalala", "package", "paackage", "pakkage", "blabla"), x = c("season", NA, "package", "package", "package", NA), y2 = c("1","2", "3", "2", "4", "6"))

df_c <- data.frame(z = c("season", "sessson", "saeson", "package", "pakkage"), x = c("season", "season", "season", "package", "package"), y3 = c("1","2", "3", "2","6"))

df_a
        x x1
1  season  1
2  season  2
3  season  3
4 package  1
5 package  6

df_b
        y       x y2
1  seaason  season  1
2   lalala    <NA>  2
3  package package  3
4 paackage package  2
5  pakkage package  4
6   blabla    <NA>  6

df_c
        z       x y3
1  season  season  1
2 sessson  season  2
3  saeson  season  3
4 package package  2
5 pakkage package  6
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not interested in fuzzyjoining your way out of this, the two choices I can see are named lists/vectors (which are essentially a dictionary structure) and the hash library. For simplicity you should probably aim for named lists.

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

my_list <- c("sexson" = "season", "paackage" = "package", "pakkage" = "package")


df_b %>%
     mutate(x = str_replace_all(x, my_list, names(my_list))
```

You could also look at the Hunspell package to avoid doing this manually.

Say if you had the lists already set up in a df, we could extract the incorrect text as one list, the correct text as another list and then set the names accordingly and replace like so:

```
incorrect <- df_b$y
correct <- df_b$x

names(correct) <- incorrect

df_b %>%
  mutate(y = str_replace_all(y, correct, names(correct)))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer jpenzer. I think I might however oversimplified my example a bit. I was hoping to find a more robust solution. I made some changes to my example to reflect this. Also the Hunspell package is a nice idea, but in my actual data the problem is not caused by spelling mistakes (but by using synonyms for example).

Comment: Sure - you may want to produce a new reprex that gets at the heart of what you want to do - it’s hard for us to know what you want. From what I can see the named vector approach is sufficient. Dictionaries in Python for example are based loosely on named vectors. 

You could build up your dictionary to have a many to one solution, as in replace all of seasson, sexson etc. -> with ‘season’. The virtue of this approach is once your dictionary is built it’s simple to correct all. The vice is that constructing the dictionary is time consuming.